# django form doesn't work on click submit

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to do a form, with gender choices. The user could choice between male or female.

What I have now in forms.py:

```
class GenderForm(forms.Form):
    demo = DemoData.objects.all()
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('Male', 'Masculino'),
        ('Female', 'Feminino')]

    gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(demo, widget=Select(), required=True)
    choices_distlabel = [('', '')] + GENDER_CHOICES
    gender.choices =  choices_distlabel
```

in the template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% for field in form_gender %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form> 
{% if idgender %}
    <img src="/age_gender/{{ idgender }}.png" alt="Graph"/>
{% endif %}
```

the views:

```
 if form_gender.is_valid():
        gender = form_gender.cleaned_data['gender']
        gender = gender.gender
        if gender:
            idgender = gender
        return render_to_response('age.html', {'form_gender': form_gender, 'idgender': idgender })
```

the form is done and works, but the problem is when I click on the submit button nothing happen. He is not given me the information

Comment: what is meant by "nothing happen"? The form is not submitted or it is, but you don't get any data from it?

Comment: Actually I was able to make it work a while ago. The form wasn't being validated. I made a fews changes at the form and now it work

Answer (score 2):

You have to define url where post data will be sent

This will send post data to url /my_app/my_view/

```
<form action="/my_app/my_view/" method="post">
    {% for field in form_gender %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This will send post data to current url you are on.

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% for field in form_gender %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that way also, but that's not the reason why it doesn't work. Nothing change..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you've defined DemoDataForm in both models.py and forms.py, once as a ModelForm and once as a plain form. Because of that, it's impossible to tell from the code you've posted exactly which class you're instantiating.

I would say, drop the version in forms.py, move the one in models.py into forms.py, and use that. But first you'll need to fix a slight bug - instead of:

```
fields = ('gender')
```

you need

```
fields = ('gender',)
```

because a one-item tuple always needs a comma, otherwise Python will try to iterate through the string.

Comment: Actually it was a silly mistake, I forgot a brackets. sorry about that, but I wasn't see the error. But thank you for your suggestion. I saw in django documentation and I tried like that

Comment: I gone update my question and post my final result. Feel free to suggest improvements :)